# What is the best means to get the unique hash data into a JSON object without using an array when cycling through a DB Dataset?

Tags: json, perl, hash

I need to get the data into a JSON object but because I'm using the `%data` hash and it has the same address I'm getting the same data repeatedly in my JSON object.

This is the code that produces the JSON.

```
            while (my ($orderID, $possessorName, $itemDescription, $...) = $sth->fetchrow_array) 
        {
            %data = (orderID => $orderID, possessorName => $possessorName, itemDescription => $itemDescription,...);


            $query_results{"job$index"} = {"data" => \%data};

            $index++;

        }




        return $json_obj->pretty->encode(\%query_results, {ascii => 1, pretty => 1});
```

The problem is that the last item in my data set is masking all the previous items so I end up with one large JSON of the same exact data.  I could use an array of hashes I suppose but this seems really messy and sloppy.  How do I write the cleanest code to get my data?  If an array of hashes is the best way to go please let me know and I'll do it.  I all ready know how or can figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you try:

```
my $index = 0;
my %query_results;

while (my ($orderID, $possessorName, $itemDescription, $...) = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    my %data = (orderID => $orderID, possessorName => $possessorName, itemDescription => $itemDescription,...);
    $query_results{"job$index"}{'data'} = \%data;
    $index++;
}
```

Previously, you used a `%data` hash declared in an outside scope; or worse, you didn't `use strict; use warnings` so `%data` was in fact an implicit global. Now, we declare the `%data` *inside* the loop which makes all the hashes distinct.

You could also copy the hash into a new hashref by `{%data}`.

That said, you don't even need that variable:

```
$query_results{"job$index"}{data} = {
  # anonymous hashref here
  orderID          => $orderId,
  possessorName    => $possessorName,
  itemDescription  => ...
};
```